# What to do when you do not get an answer after 1 year

Tags: peer-review, paper-submission

I am in the situation where I submitted an article 1 year and 4 months ago. I already asked to editors about the status nearly five months ago and they replied they are still waiting for the referee answer and that they were going to ask to expedite the process.

I didn’t receive other news since them, and I don’t know if it will be time to contact them again. Would it be considered impolite? What is your suggestion?

Comment: You should contact them ASAP. Considered impolite or not, you have the right for a timely review.

Comment: Then you should ask again.  If that doesn't work: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/16502/19607

Comment: You might want to state your field, though in this case this only serves to distinguish between such classifications as *very long* and *outrageously long.*

Comment: Thanks everyone for the comments; however, it is a rather simple review article in elementary number theory (approx 10 pages), that's the reason why I am a bit disappointed :/ [Probably it is not the case to quote the  journal name]

Comment: Ah, math. Reviewers do not like to taint their brain with infectious ideas from others, so they sip the paper only line by line.

Comment: Related question: http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/48306/almost-14-months-after-submission-the-associate-editor-informed-me-they-still-di

Comment: I don't think 1 year and 4 months is that long for a pure math paper. That is why it should be placed on the arxiv, although if it is a review perhaps that is long (depends on how dense it is and if there are new insights).

Comment: @WetLabStudent That is long for even a rather involved math paper.  It is very long for a short elementary article.

Comment: Well, now it is more than 2.5 years.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that if you've not heard anything after a year then either they have a HUGE backlog of papers or they have rejected your paper and did not have the decency to tell you. Sorry. I think we've all been there at least once. :-(

Comment: It's happened to me several times.